# How to refactor this Model logic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, refactoring, rails-activerecord

I am having teacher model and it has got many students. Then student has got many subjects. 
Based on this relation i need to prepare a report..

Here I am just combining every entity by includes statement, then looping around to get data in required format(array of hash).

```
#teacher.rb

      def get_students_report
        teachers = Teacher.includes(students: :subjects)

        final_result = []
        teachers.each do |teacher|
          students = teacher.students
          teacher_name = teacher.full_name
          classes_taken = teacher.classes_count 

          students.each do |student|
            student_name = student.name
            attendance = (student.days_attended/classes_taken.to_f) * 100.0
            subjects = student.subjects
            final_result = 0
            subject_total = subjects.sum(:marks_obtained)
            #show in percentage
            mark_in_percentage = (subject_total * 100)/subjects.sum(:maximum_mark).to_f 

            students_record = {
              student_name: student_name
              teacher_name: teacher_name
              attendance: attendance, 
              subject_total: subject_total
              subject_percentage: mark_in_percentage
            }
            final_result.push student_record

         end #end of student loop
        end #end of teacher loop
      end  #end of method.
```

Above solution works fine. but I feel this has got following flaws: 
- this method is too big and in future if i need more column then this will grow more.
- Code can't be well maintained.

Can we have better approach for this ?

Comment: For starters, this looks like it should be a class method.

Comment: Secondly, there are a lot of unnecessary assignment statements. There shouldn't be much performance difference between storing `student_name` vs. just calling `student.name`.

Comment: I would make a method on `Student` that is `def record_for_teacher(teacher)` and move most of the student block logic to the `Student` model.

Comment: With record_for_teacher, we will get student_name, attendance, marks_in_percentage, subject_total from the student model, so around 4/5lines of code can be minimized ?

is Student Model a better place to move on ? Because those calculations are not performing that serious DB operations ? Any help from decorator/concern can be used ?

Comment: What's the relationship between teacher and student? A teacher `has_many` students, but does a student `belong_to` a teacher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a teacher `has_many` students and a student `belongs_to` a teacher, you could to the following:

**Teacher.rb**

```
has_many :students, inverse_of: :teacher

def self.get_students_report
  self.includes(student: :subjects).map(&:students_reports).flatten
end

def students_reports
  students.map(&:record).flatten
end
```

**Student.rb**

```
belongs_to :teacher, inverse_of: :students

def record
  {
    student_name: name,
    teacher_name: teacher.name,
    attendance: attendance, 
    subject_total: subject_total,
    subject_percentage: mark_in_percentage
  }
end

private

def attendance
  (student.days_attended/classes_taken.to_f) * 100.0
end

def classes_taken
  teacher.classes_count
end

def subject_total
  subjects.sum(:marks_obtained)
end

def mark_in_percentage
  (subject_total * 100)/subjects.sum(:maximum_mark).to_f
end
```

Comment: You are my man! You sound absolutely reasonable. I will definitely give a try to this approach and get back here at the earliest ! Thanks  again :)